# Debería escribir las tablas de multiplicar pero solo imprime la del uno (tiene que ser con un bucle while anidado

Tags: python

No se porque solo me escribe la tabla del uno, se supone que el primer ciclo while tendría que repetirse hasta el 10.

```
limite = 10
numero = 1
resultado = 1
contador = 1
tabla = 1
while tabla < 10:
    tabla = tabla + 1
    print('\n')
    while contador <= limite:
        resultado = contador * numero
        print (resultado, end=' ')
        contador = contador + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate que estableces `contador = 1` al principio ... y no lo vuelves a *reiniciar* a `1`, con lo que tu bucle interno falla en cuanto terminas la tabla del 1.

Simplemente, inicializa `contador` **dentro** del bucle externo.

Además, puesto que haces `tabla = 1` y luego lo incrementas en el bucle, deberías iniciarla a `0`.

Por último, debería ser `resultado = contador * tabla`:

```
limite = 10
tabla = 0

while tabla < 10:
    contador = 1
    tabla = tabla + 1
    print('\n')

    while contador <= limite:
        resultado = contador * tabla
        print (resultado, end=' ')
        contador = contador + 1
```

Comment: Justo. este era el error. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 2):

El error está en que nunca reinicias `contador`, por lo que la condición de  `while contador <= limite:` ya no se cumple más. Tienes que reinicializar `contador=1` antes de entrar a ese `while`.

Las tablas se pueden calcular e imprimir asi:

```
for tabla in range(11):
    for val in range(1, 11):
        print(tabla, " * ", val, "=", tabla*val)
    print('\n')
```

Comment: sii ese era el error, lo resolví con el ciclo for pero no me validaban la respuesta, pedían que fuera un while anidado.

Comment: @zodiak. `for` es lo apropiado cuando conoces cuantas iteraciones hacer; `while` lo usas cuando esperas a que se cumpla una condición.